# Temporarily suspend snapping in QGIS

Tags: qgis, snapping

Is it possible to temporarily suspend snapping with a shortcut Key in Qgis, like its possible holding down space in Arcmap?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about older versions, but in QGIS 3.10.1 there is a default hotkey for snapping enabling/disabling - "S"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if turning it on/off with a single key is supported. You can create a shortcut to bring up the snapping options from:

*Settings > Configure Shortcuts > Snapping Options...*

This lets you quickly set the option **Snap to** on/off instead of going through the toolbar.

I would be interested to see if there is a method using a single key but hope this helps anyway!

Comment: Tnx Joseph, but what i need is to just press the key and snapping is suspended. I think this is a very important feature for anyone who is digitizing a lot. This is on of the reasons i always use Arcmap for digitizing and editing.

Comment: @RolandG, I agree!